# Creating markers in GoogleMaps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How to create a function for drawing markers on a map from an array of applications received during the operation. That is, the function must be outside the viewDidLoad() ?
If you use a simple function with the following content:

```html
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var mMap: GMSMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let mapInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 100.0, right: 0.0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    view = mMap
    mMap.padding = mapInsets 
    mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true 
    mMap.settings.compassButton = true 
    mMap.settings.myLocationButton = true 
    mMap.settings.scrollGestures = true
    mMap.settings.zoomGestures = true

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: myLat, longitude: myLon, zoom: 15.0)
    let mMap = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera) 

    let buttonDps = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 520, width: 103, height: 45))
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.setTitle("yes", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 19)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0   
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAct), for:.touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

}

func buttonAct(sender: UIButton!) {        
    let alert = UIAlertController(title:"help", message:"qwerty", preferredStyle:.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style:.default){ action in
    self.markercreate()                        
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"cancel", style:.cancel, handler:nil))
    self.present(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
    
}
        func markercreate(){
            let marker2 = GMSMarker()
            marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 54.9044200,             longitude: 52.3154000)
            marker2.title = "Россия"
            marker2.snippet = "Москва"
            marker2.map = mMap
        }
}
```

then nothing happens (((

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: If the creation of markers does not occur in the viewDidLoad, they are not created on the map. If I set the marker inside the viewDidLoad: '        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.7522200, 
        longitude: 37.6155600)
        marker.title = "Россия"
        marker.snippet = "Москва"
        marker.map = mMap'
that markers are created. But I can not do this because the data to create the markers I load during the application, and I need to put them on the card after it is already created.

Comment: From where are you calling this method?

Comment: From another method after receiving data from the server and creating an array with coordinates

Comment: Add more code..

Comment: Added code above

Comment: In your code you have created 2 mMap variables. 1st: Outlet, 2nd: ViewDidLoad. And why you are adding button through code and not in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can analyze,

The code will work fine. Also the `marker` is added to the `map`. **You just don't see the marker you have added**. Move the `camera position` of the `map` to `marker` position so that you can see the marker, i.e.

```
func markercreate()
{
    //Your code...
    mMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 54.9044200, longitude: 52.3154000, zoom: 15.0) //Add this line to your code
}
```

I assume you will resolve the 2 `mMap` variables that you have created as I mentioned in the comment.

**Edit:**

**1.** In `Storyboard`, set the `ViewController's` `view's` `class` to `GMSMapView` and connect the `outlet` `mMap` to it, i.e.

[image]

**2.** Follow the `comments` in the below code snippet:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Your code...

    view = mMap //Remove this line
    mMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 54.9044200, longitude: 52.3154000, zoom: 15.0) //Add this line
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: myLat, longitude: myLon, zoom: 15.0) //Remove this line
    let mMap = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera) //Remove this line

    //Your code...
}
```

Comment: I myself am in this place, and when I press the button a myLocationButton camera moves me to my location and there's still no this marker there. If I add your code to my function, then the application displays an error

Comment: Then the map is not displayed and the application gives an error (((

Comment: Why is it giving you error? You are using a separate view for map for which you have taken the outlet right?

Comment: I did everything as you advised, but still there was a error. In the end, everything was deleted, and started a new project, in which he did everything as you advised and now it works! Thank you very much for the help and patience shown to me!

Comment: Sure..Accept and upvote the answer..Happy coding..:)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a list of latitude, longitude and place name.
Create a loop and inside your loop if you want to show markers then use this.

```
func createMarker()
{
    let lon = Double(longResult as! String)

    let lat = Double(latResult as! String)

    print("Center_Name: \(centerName)")

    print("Longitude: \(longResult)")

    print("Latitude: \(latResult)")

    let markerResult = GMSMarker()

    markerResult.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat!  , longitude: lon!)

    markerResult.title = "\(centerName)"

    markerResult.map = viewMap
}
```

The code I have shown is a basic one. With this you can create a marker on your map.